# Windows Server Backup : The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup, windows-7, virtualbox, windows-server-backup

> The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect

[image]

This is a virtual Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard version running on Virtual Host installed on a Windows 7 ultimate. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the role? Also, try doing a manual backup through wbadmin command line tools.

Comment: Just to clarify: Windows Server Backup is a Feature, not a Role.

Comment: This is the background of how I started seeing the problem. I installed the Windows Server Backup from PowerShell and later on installed the Command-line Tools from the Control Panel.

Comment: @TheD I re-installed the feature and tried both 'Backup Schedule' and 'Backup Once'. I am getting the same error message.

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes, sorry, feature! Have you tried using wbadmin through command prompt to run a backup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with Backup an Win2008 R2 server in VirtualBox over a shared folder. My solution was a second virtual VHD drive (VHD because of restore into Hyper-V), where i backed up onto. That worked for me at the end and I could restore from that drive into Hyper-V afterwards as well.